# Line segments intersection, numerically stable test

Tags: c++, testing, intersection, numerical

I need a precise and numerically stable test for 2 line segments intersection in 2D. There is one possible solution detecting 4 postions, see bellow the code.

```
getInters ( double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4, double & x_int, double & y_int  )
{
    3: Intersect in two end points,
    2: Intersect in one end point,
    1: Intersect (but not in end points)
    0: Do not intersect 

unsigned short code = 2;

//Initialize intersections
x_int = 0, y_int = 0;

//Compute denominator
    double denom =  x1 * ( y4 - y3 ) + x2 * ( y3 - y4 ) + x4 * ( y2 - y1 ) + x3 * ( y1 - y2 ) ;

    //Segments are parallel
if ( fabs ( denom ) < eps)
    {
            //Will be solved later
    }

//Compute numerators
    double numer1 =     x1 * ( y4 - y3 ) + x3 * ( y1 - y4 ) + x4 * ( y3 - y1 );
double numer2 = - ( x1 * ( y3 - y2 ) + x2 * ( y1 - y3 ) + x3 * ( y2 - y1 ) );

//Compute parameters s,t
    double s = numer1 / denom;
    double t = numer2 / denom;

    //Both segments intersect in 2 end points: numerically more accurate than using s, t
if ( ( fabs (numer1) < eps)  && ( fabs (numer2) < eps) || 
     ( fabs (numer1) < eps)  && ( fabs (numer2 - denom) < eps) ||
     ( fabs (numer1 - denom)  < eps)  && ( fabs (numer2) < eps) || 
     ( fabs (numer1 - denom) < eps) &&  ( fabs (numer2 - denom) < eps) )
    {
            code =  3;
    }

//Segments do not intersect: do not compute any intersection
    else if ( ( s < 0.0 ) || ( s > 1 ) || 
      ( t < 0.0 ) || ( t > 1 ) )
    {
            return  0;
    }

    //Segments intersect, but not in end points
    else if ( ( s > 0 ) && ( s < 1 ) && ( t > 0 ) && ( t < 1 ) )
    {
            code =  1;
    }

//Compute intersection
x_int = x1 + s * ( x2 - x1 );
y_int = y1 + s * ( y2 - y1 );

//Segments intersect in one end point
return code;
 }
```

I am not sure whether all proposed conditions are designed properly (to avoid roundness errors).

Does it make sense to use the parameters s, t for testing or use it only for the computation of an intersection?

I am afraid that position 2 (segment intersect in one end point) may not be correctly detected (last remaining situation without any condition)...

Comment: Idea: 1st check for for the degenerate cases (parallel, incident or disjoint). 2nd compute the intersection point. 3rd check if the intersection lies on either segment, and if yes where. If you can afford to use rationals rather than reals, you can even get a precise answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems as a very common math problem. There's a good tutorial with formulas on topcoder that answers your question and it is easy to implement the fundamentals in whatever programming language you want: [Line Intersection Tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=geometry2)

Regards,
Evgenia

Answer (score 0):

```
if(fabs(denom) < eps){
    if((fabs(len(x2, y2, x3, y3) + len(x2, y2, x4, y4) - len(x3, y3, x4, y4)) < eps) || (fabs(len(x1, y1, x3, y3) + len(x1, y1, x4, y4) - len(x3, y3, x4, y4)) < eps) || (fabs(len(x3, y3, x1, y1) + len(x3, y3, x2, y2) - len(x1, y1, x2, y2)) < eps) || (fabs(len(x4, y4, x1, y1) + len(x4, y4, x2, y2) - len(x1, y1, x2, y2)) < eps)){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Where `len = sqrt(sqr(c - a) + sqr(d - b))`